# MFC SDI read from an INI and update view string while changing attributes

Tags: c++, mfc, sdi

First time post, so forgive any improper etiquette i may bring.

My title briefly describes the problem i have. I have a school project where I start with a MFC application with a single document view and i need to display just a simple text onto my view BUT this text comes from a simple INI file.

```
LPCTSTR path = _T("C:\\Users\\Steve\\Documents\\WhereDataIs.ini");
TCHAR INIValue[256];
GetPrivateProfileString(_T("SETUP"), _T("Introduction"), _T("File Could Not Be Found"), INIValue, 256, path);
```

Okay now my ini file just contains this...

```
[SETUP]

Introduction = Here is your data
```

Up to this point, everything is going well. The next step is to grab the 'static text box' i created in the resource editor and change it to the data from the ini which is just 'Here is your data'.

```
SetDlgItemText(StringToChange, INIValue);
```

and this works perfect. So i managed to change what i wanted as desired but now comes the hard part. I need to bold the entire string before using

```
SetDlgItemText(StringToChange, INIValue);
```

I have run into so many problems in the last 5 days. I have tried everything i have run across on google and stack overflow. I ran into trying to use a RTF control? trying to convert to html bolding it and then coming back? issues with 8bit or 16bit? unicode or something along those lines. i've ran into macros like _T("some string") that apparently doesn't take a variable of type string. Nothing has worked for me. What i really could use is some kind of example, it doesn't have to relate to mine at all. Something i can work with a base from. And before you link me to another website or a previous post - i guarantee you I've already looked at it and tried it. I'd really like someone to post a small part of code to help get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use font with bold style to achieve what you need:

```
 m_font.CreateFont(16, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, FALSE, FALSE, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET,
 OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, 
 DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS, _T("MS Sans Serif"));
 m_YourStaticControl.SetFont(&m_font);
```

make `CFont m_font;` a member of your class (put it in header file).

If you want more flexibility use RichEdit control. Here is helper function that appends text using different styles:

```
void AddToRichText(CRichEditCtrl &rEdit, const CString& sNewText, COLORREF color, BOOL bBold, BOOL bUnderline, BOOL bItalic)
{
    int iTotalTextLength = rEdit.GetWindowTextLength();

    rEdit.SetSel(iTotalTextLength, iTotalTextLength);

    CHARFORMAT cf;
    cf.cbSize = sizeof(CHARFORMAT);
    cf.dwMask = CFM_COLOR | CFM_UNDERLINE | CFM_BOLD | CFM_ITALIC;

    DWORD dwEffects = CFE_AUTOCOLOR;
    if (!bBold)
        dwEffects |= CFE_BOLD;

    if (!bUnderline)
        dwEffects |= CFE_UNDERLINE;

    if (!bItalic)
        dwEffects |= CFE_ITALIC;

    cf.dwEffects = (unsigned long)~dwEffects;

    cf.crTextColor = color;
    rEdit.SetSelectionCharFormat(cf);

    rEdit.ReplaceSel(sNewText);
    rEdit.HideSelection(TRUE, FALSE);
}
```

Comment: non-RichText: you will need to add the code in `YourDlg::OnInitDialog()` after the call to 'CDialog[Ex]::OnInitDialog()'; the call to set the font would be `StringToChange.SetFont(&m_font);`

Comment: Okay so the first option worked wonders! it took the whole thing and made it bold. Is there any way to make just a word bold instead of the whole control? considering that we're setting the WHOLE control with that kind of font, i would think not. I am currently looking into a RichEdit Control so i can play around with the code you provided.

Comment: @StevenV For regular edit box you would have to make it owner draw.